# Form Validation Via Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, radio-group

ı have to many radio group and you have to select at least 1 in each group. and ı dont want to use html "required".

ı wrote someting with jquery but it doesnt work.

ı just want to learn where ı do wrong.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

     $(".radiogrup").each(function(){

         var sel=$(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    if(sel==null){
         alert("error msg"); return false;  

    }
    else {
        //submit form and do something.
    }

    });
})
```

but if any of them leave blank it shouldnt submit form.

Comment: what happens when that code runs? From first impression, i don't think you need the `val()`...

Comment: it submits form any way. if you dont leave blank any of radio groups.

Comment: sel maybe equal undefined, can you clarify this? sel.length should be `> 0`. have you tried to debug this?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with sel, it works. if you dont check radio it show error but when you select any of them it submits form.

Comment: Maybe you should expand on your question, because it's difficult to understand. However, from what I can tell your code will submit the form if one radio button of group `.radiogrup` is checked.

Comment: Spare yourself some pain and use [an validation existing library](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/); it supports adding your own validation functions easily so can be adapted for pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
var sel=$(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
if(sel==null){ /* Error */ }
```

with

```
if($(this).find(':radio:checked').length == 0) { /* Error */ }
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJa7a/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){


 var sel= 'true';
 $(".myRadio").each(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      sel = 'false';
    }
 })

if(sel=='true'){
     alert("error msg"); return false;  

}
else {
    //submit form and do something.
   return true;
}
```

})

Comment: sel is use as flag initial it is true if logic found any of the radio selected then it is set to false and the depending on it value we will return form to be submmited or not

Comment: my point being that your treating it as a string in some instances, and then as a boolean in others?